# Creating custom section Umbraco 4.11

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have recently upgraded to the newest Umbraco 4.11.1 and the old way to create custom sections doesn't seem to work any more. Which isn't a bad thing because that didn't really work well. However I can't seem to find any information at all on how to create one in the newer versions.

I found [this blog post](http://blog.mattbrailsford.com/2012/07/18/creating-custom-applications-and-trees-in-umbraco-4-8/):

> as from here on the entries for applications and application trees have now been moved to config files located in the config folder. Unsurprisingly, these are named applications.config and trees.config.

However I don't even have **applications.config** and **trees.config**.

And I can't find any other information about this.

Thank you,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you upgraded the site, you probably didn't copy any files from the config folder. I'd suggest copying the applications.config and trees.config from the zip you downloaded for the upgrade.

Comment: Nah, don't feel stupid... The general upgrade instructions only talk about the bin, umbraco, and umbraco_client folder. You're welcome!

Comment: Oh, and that brings up an important point. You may want to look back and make sure the follow the specific upgrade instructions and make sure you are adding any new config entries.